# Use of a specific column

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Hello everyone, 
I have been working on the calculation of a value in a pivot table but after hours of research, I cannot figure out how to get what I want.
In a pivot table, I would like to use a specific column for a calculated value.
Here what my data look like :

[image: Pivot Table]

For each column d1, d2 and d3, I would like to add a calculated field with the following formula : 
`metrics3[d_n] = metrics1[d_n]*(metrics2[d0]/metrics1[d0])` where **n** is 1, 2 or 3.

In other words, I would like for each d1, d2, d3 to use the values of d0 to calculate a new value. Here is what it would be if I were to not use a pivot table :

[image: Pivot Table]

The only way to fix d0 and to calculate a field for each d is to use :

[image: Ratio_calculation]

With that, I get the following table :

[image: table_with_ratio]

The only thing that I would have to do to solve my issue is to calculate :`(Somme de d_compared_to_d0_2/Somme de d_compared_to_d0_1)-1` 
But I don't know how to do that (The trick I used for the last 2 pictures are only visualisation features, I cannot use these values to calculate a new field).

Do you see another way to reach my goal ?

I understand if my explanations are unclear, I would be happy to make it clearer if you need.

Thank you so much ! :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I've reviewed your post multiple times and am still not sure what you want.  I also am not sure how the Pivot Table relates to the source data.  I suggest you review site guidelines on [ask] and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then [edit] your post instead of adding information in a comment.

Comment: Hello Rey, thank you for this comment, I tried to change everything to make thing clearer, is that better ?

Comment: I think it is more understandable now, however I don't know how to do it so hopefully someone else does.  However, to make it clearer I suggest that you look at your first formula `metrics3[d] =` and compare that to what you have in your first image.  They don't seem to agree.